# Xcode 3.2 crashes when opening/creating a project

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, xcode3.2

Xcode 3.2 crashes when opening/creating a project. Log really explains the rest (OS version etc.)

LOG:

```
Process:         Xcode [7718]
Path:            /Xcode3.2/*/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.Xcode
Version:         3.2 (1610)
Build Info:      DevToolsIDE-16100000~6
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [224]

Date/Time:       2011-11-23 22:00:45.656 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.2 (11C74)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          172469 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           8
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  19398 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      5085CBA9-0FEA-4928-84A9-B5802B0A1903

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Performing @selector(overwriteSelectedAction:) from sender NSButton 0x401ab2520
objc[7718]: garbage collection is ON

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _dispatch_queue_attr_create
  Referenced from: /Xcode3.2/*/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../Library/PrivateFrameworks//DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsCore
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   dyld                            0x00007fff68fd906d dyld_fatal_error + 1
1   dyld                            0x00007fff68fdc918 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 128
2   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9281d716 dyld_stub_binder_ + 13
3   ???                             0x0000000100550010 0 + 4300537872
4   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001001167a7 -[PBXProjectIndex initWithProject:] + 87
5   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000100116479 -[PBXProject loadIndex] + 137
6   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000100116304 -[PBXProject beginIndexing] + 52
7   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001001162cb -[PBXProject openIndex] + 43
8   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface   0x0000000100870b7f -[PBXProjectDocument initWithProject:] + 367
9   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface   0x000000010096db80 +[PBXProjectDocument documentWithProject:] + 48
10  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface   0x00000001009d2bff -[PBXProjectWizard _finishTemplateInstantiationAfterFileCopying:instantiationResult:] + 351
11  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface   0x0000000100a765eb -[PBXFileCopyingWizard _finishCopyingTemplate:filesToPreserve:] + 219
12  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface   0x0000000100a9b780 -[PBXWizardOverwritingFilesModule sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:] + 368
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91d317d7 -[NSApplication endSheet:returnCode:] + 275
14  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface   0x0000000100a9b84e -[PBXWizardOverwritingFilesModule overwriteSelectedAction:] + 78
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9129fa1d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91b80710 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91b80642 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 88
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91b8056d -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 137
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91b7fa30 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2014
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91bff8e0 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 489
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91b7e63a -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91b490e0 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6306
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91ae168f -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
24  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface   0x0000000100869bdd -[PBXExtendedApplication sendEvent:] + 301
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91a77682 -[NSApplication run] + 555
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91cf680c NSApplicationMain + 867
27  com.apple.Xcode                 0x000000010000e97e 0x100000000 + 59774
28  com.apple.Xcode                 0x0000000100001844 0x100000000 + 6212

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bcbf7e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8bc205be _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8bc1f14e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bcbd67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bcbcd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9123cb6c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff912452d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91244ae6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x00000001094da094 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 229
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff942fe7fe -[NSThread main] + 68
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff942fe776 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d0798bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d07cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bcbedf2 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9128df9b __CFSocketManager + 1355
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d0798bf _pthread_start + 335
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d07cb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bcbf192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d07b594 _pthread_wqthread + 758  
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d07cb85 start_wqthread + 13

...*snip* - Rest at http://pastebin.com/BLsUxEkz
```

(Sorry, the log is LONG and putting 4 spaces at the begging of over 450 lines is too much! The rest of the log is at: http://pastebin.com/BLsUxEkz)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: The only reason I wanted to use Xcode 3 (I usually use 4) is that I want to test my iOS app on iOS 3.x.**

Comment: @Gabe. The only reason I wanted to use Xcode 3 (I usually use 4) is that I want to test my iOS app on iOS 3.x. Although I have upgraded to 3.2.6 (see my answer below) and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Xcode 3.2.6 seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 3 is not officially supported on Mac OS X Lion.

Either upgrade to Xcode 4 (you can still target Mac OS X versions older than 10.7), or stick to Snow Leopard.

Otherwise, if you really want to use Lion and Xcode 3, I think you should install a 10.6 virtual machine, so you can run Xcode 3.

Comment: The only reason I wanted to use Xcode 3 (I usually use 4) is that I want to test my iOS app on iOS 3.x. Unless there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I heard some people said they couldn't run xcode3 on lion,so I think snow leopard well be chosen if you want use xcode3.     Best regard.